# Pass text from console to context

Tags: context, linux, terminal-output, console

I want pass text from console to context, like this

```
echo "\starttext Hello, World! \stoptext" | context -
```

but this does not work. It seems that context just could be invoked against a file (`context somefile.tex`)

Is it possible?
I prefer solutions to MKIV (not LMTX)

Comment: If context won't read from STDIN (no idea), a temporary file would probably be your best option. `echo "\starttext Hello, World! \stoptext" > temp.tex && context temp.tex` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I just want to know if context could be read or not from STDIN

Comment: ConTeXt does read from stdin, but it expects filenames instead of content.

Comment: @HenriMenke Can you please put references of that behaviour? It could be simulate using sh utils?

Comment: @somenxavier Ingmar's comment above is the best you can do with shell utilities. ConTeXt does not read input from pipes, especially because TeX always needs an output directory to write at least the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--pipe`:

```
echo '\starttext foo\stoptext' | context --luatex --pipe --dummyfile=foo
```

This will create `foo.pdf`.